# Changing z-index to make a clicked div appear on top

Tags: jquery, css, z-index

In my application I can open several div boxes that overlap each other. When clicking on a box that box should be moved to the top. What is the best way to accomplish this?

The only thing I can think of is looping through all the boxes z-index values to get the highest value, and then add 1 to that value and apply it on the clicked div.

Any advices for me?

Comment: Code, figure, anything help us to understand what you want! I just cant understand how can I click on box if that box is behind another box ! or you need to be that parts of that boxes are shown!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

something like this should do it:

```
// Set up on DOM-ready
$(function() {
    // Change this selector to find whatever your 'boxes' are
    var boxes = $("div");

    // Set up click handlers for each box
    boxes.click(function() {
        var el = $(this), // The box that was clicked
            max = 0;

        // Find the highest z-index
        boxes.each(function() {
            // Find the current z-index value
            var z = parseInt( $( this ).css( "z-index" ), 10 );
            // Keep either the current max, or the current z-index, whichever is higher
            max = Math.max( max, z );
        });

        // Set the box that was clicked to the highest z-index plus one
        el.css("z-index", max + 1 );
    });
});
```

Comment: Interesting solution. But why are you using parseInt in this case? Thanks for the answer by the way!

Comment: sure! i used `parseInt` because calling $().css("z-index") is going to return the element's z-index as a string, but we need a number to pass to Math.max.

Comment: actually, `Math.max()` will convert strings to numbers automatically, but the default value for elements without an explicit z-index is 'auto' which will return `NaN` when passed to `Math.max()`

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you have elements with a specific class ("box" in my example) and that all are in the same container like this :

```
<div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Assuming you have the correct css :

```
.box {position:absolute; z-index:10}
```

You can use the jquery js code below :

```
$('.box').click(function() {
   // set ohters element to the initial level
   $(this).siblings('.box').css('z-index', 10);
   // set clicked element to a higher level
   $(this).css('z-index', 11);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

I would approach this by making a jQuery plugin, so you don't have to worry about manually setting the `z-index` and keeping track of the highest value with a variable:

```js
(function() {
    var highest = 1;

    $.fn.bringToTop = function() {
        this.css('z-index', ++highest); // increase highest by 1 and set the style
    };
})();

$('div.clickable').click(function() {
    $(this).bringToTop();
});
```

This wouldn't work well if you set `z-index` with any other code on your page.

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this with jquery:

$('#div').click(function(){$(this).css('zIndex', '10000'});

this will work as long as the z-index for all underlying divs is lower than 10000. or, you could write a function to iterate all divs and get the highest z-index and move the clicked on to that number +1.

Answer (score 0):

your idea of getting the highest z-index is the way to go I think.

however, instead of looping through it on each click, I would loop through it only once on the load of the page and maintain an object that stores the highest z-index.

```
CONSTANTS = {
    highest_z_index = 0;
};

function getHighestZ (){
    var $divs = $('div');

    $.each($divs,function(){
        if (this.css('z-index') > CONSTANTS.highest_z_index){
            CONSTANTS.highest_z_index = this.css('z-index');
        }
    });
}

getHighestZ();

$('#YourDiv').click(function(){
    if (CONSTANTS.highest_z_index > $(this).css('z-index'){
         $(this).css('z-index',++CONSTANTS.highest_z_index);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple! `$(".classname").on("click",function(){$(".classname").css('z-index',0);$(this).css('z-index',1);});`