# Images with alternating z-indexes JQuery UI

Tags: jquery-ui, z-index, draggable

I found another question with a similar issue but couldn't make head nor tail of how to apply the solution. My webpage is a simple combination of draggable images that lap over each other. All I want is for an image to appear on top of the others when clicked.

Each mage is currently functioning as a span element for dragging - do I need to have all individual images as div elements for a solution to work? do I need to apply an initial z-index to each image? (right now no z-indexes have been applied)

Here is the code I'm working with

```
<div id="wrapper">

<span id="drag" style=""><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="paragraphAnchor">    
<img src="images/logoweb.png" width="198" height="198" style="" /></a></span>

<div id="text">   

<p id='a'>

<span style="background:#0C6;">

text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text   
<br/><br/>


<a href="#">website</a>

<br/><br/>

<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="paragraphAnchor5">close</a>


</p>

</span>
```

and the JQuery for each element

```
$(document).ready(function()

                        {

                            $('#drag').draggable( { containment: 'window' } );/*.resizable();*/






                        });
```

```
 $(document).ready(function()
                       {

                        $('p#a').hide();
                        $('p#b').hide();


                        $('a#paragraphAnchor') .click(function() {
                             return false;
                              }).dblclick(function() 

                                                             {

                                                                 $('p#a').slideToggle('slow');
                                                                 $('p#b').hide();


                                                             });
```

This is the code I've found for a similar query [Changing z-index to make a clicked div appear on top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8568158/changing-z-index-to-make-a-clicked-div-appear-on-top). I've been trying to integrate the solution into my own code but don't know where I'm going wrong.. It could be either confusing elements or bad coding on my part

Just starting out using JQuery, any help to fit in the solution would be really really appreciated. I'm sure it's something simple no doubt

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't seem to bear any particular reference to what you say you're trying to do. There's only one image, and clicking it just returns false. Double-clicking it makes the hidden paragraph below appear. (In general, people don't expect to have to double-click things on web pages - I'd advise against using that in most cases.)

That said, I think I understand what you're asking for, and the good news is that it's really quite simple. Here's a fiddle showing how it works: http://jsfiddle.net/ce5gw/2/

Play around with it and you'll see how it works. The three red blocks are divs designed to act like images; you can replace the `div.imgGoesHere` elements with your images. You'll notice you can drag them around, and that when you drag them, the one you're dragging is always on top. Drag the first div so it's partly on top of the second. Now click the second and you'll see it pops to the front, even without having to drag it anywhere. Problem solved.

Now I'll walk you through the code.

```
   $('.drag').draggable({
        containment: 'parent',
        stack: '.drag'
    })
```

We start off making everything of class `drag` a draggable item. They're constrained to only be draggable within the space of their parent element, which is the `div.wrapper`. You can change that back to "window" if you prefer. The most important thing here is that `stack: '.drag'`. That sets it so that, when you're dragging an item, it will always show up on top of items of class `drag` in the z-order.

But what about when you don't want to drag an item, you just want it to pop to the front when you click it? That's what the next block does.

```
   .on('click', function () {
        var el = $(this), // The image that was clicked
        max = 0;
        // Find the highest z-index
        $('.drag').each(function () {
            // Find the current z-index value
            var z = parseInt($(this).css("z-index"), 10);
            // Keep either the current max, or the current z-index, whichever is higher
            max = Math.max(max, z);
        });
        // Set the box that was clicked to the highest z-index plus one
        el.css("z-index", max + 1);
    });
```

This comes straight from the other question you linked to, and it's pretty well-explained there. Any time an element of class `drag` is clicked (this is chained to the first declaration above, so we're still talking about elements of class `drag` here) this looks at every item of class `drag`, finds the one with the highest z-index, and sets the new z-index of the clicked element to be one higher than that number.

If you have any questions about this, by all means please let me know.