# Make images come to front on click when overlapping each other

Tags: html, css

I have images that I'd like to come to front when clicking on them. I need to keep the others in their relative positions and order the same. Not sure a good way in which to do this. I attached an image that should help you further understand what I mean below:

[image: Example here]

Comment: show us your code

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: plz add a code snippet or jsfiddle link.  thanks

Comment: Just play around with the z-index

Comment: index dynamically to the images on click. Googling will give you more details about z-index and onClick event.

Comment: Possible duplicate if jQuery is used: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8568158/changing-z-index-to-make-a-clicked-div-appear-on-top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use code as below: set `z-index` onclick `img`

```js
function myFunction(x) {
  var elem = document.querySelectorAll(".img");
  for(var i=0;i<elem.length;i++){
    elem[i].style.zIndex = -1*i;
  }
  x.style.zIndex='2';
}
```

```css
.img{
width:100px;
height:100px;
position: absolute;
border:2px solid black;
}
.img:nth-child(1) {
   left:75px;
   z-index:1;
   }
.img:nth-child(2) {
    left:150px;
    z-index:-1;}
.img:nth-child(3) {
     left:225px;
     z-index:-2;}
.img:nth-child(4) {
    left:300px;
    z-index:-3;}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mG2d.jpg" onclick="myFunction(this)" class="img"/>
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mG2d.jpg" onclick="myFunction(this)" class="img"/>
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mG2d.jpg" onclick="myFunction(this)" class="img"/>
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mG2d.jpg" onclick="myFunction(this)" class="img"/>
```